# Convergence of integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}+2+\cos{x}}{x+2}dx$

Tags: analysis

Is

$$\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{4}}}<\frac{\sqrt{x}+2+\cos{x}}{x+2},\forall x>x_0$$

enough to prove that

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}+2+\cos{x}}{x+2}dx$$

diverges?

What are the standard techniques which can be used in these type of problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The integral

$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}x^{-3/4}\mathrm dx=4\left(x_1^{1/4}-x_0^{1/4}\right)$$

diverges for $x_1\to\infty$, and your integral is bounded from below by this integral (for $x_0\ge1$); hence your integral diverges.

By the way, you're missing the $\mathrm dx$ at the end of the integrals.

Answer (score 4):

For this particular exercise it suffices to use the inequality
$$
\frac{{\sqrt x  + 2 + \cos x}}{{x + 2}} \ge \frac{1}{{x + 2}}
$$
to conclude that the integral diverges, noting that $\int_1^\infty  {\frac{1}{{x + 2}}dx}  = \int_3^\infty  {\frac{1}{x}dx}  = \infty $.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The technique used here is: if $0 \le f(x) \le g(x)$ and $\int_a^b f$ diverges, then $\int_a^b g$ also diverges.  See if you can prove it!